# Display Pillow image object in Babel Org Mode directly without saving into a file?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, python, images

I wonder if there is any way for Babel in Org Mode to display images (from libraries like Pillow or matplotlib) "directly" without saving them into a file:

```
#+begin_src python
from PIL import Image
filename = 'sample-image.png'

img = Image.open(filename)

return img
#+end_src
```

However, the result is only:

```
#+RESULTS:
: <PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=RGB size=3000x1622 at 0x7F65C7170E10>
```

[Org mode documentation has a few examples](https://orgmode.org/manual/Results-of-Evaluation.html) how to show images saved into a file, but I wonder if it's possible to return them from a running code directly?